# Cap task fetches content locally

Tags: ruby, linux, capistrano

I guess some thing is wrong with this part.

```
check = %x( cat '/etc/apache2/ports.conf' )
```

I want to fetch the content from /etc/apache2/ports.conf and check if port 8581 is already listened, heres my code, Its an after deployment cap task.

```
desc "Ports Updation"
task :portsUpdation do
   # Editing /etc/apache2/ports.conf
    ports_file = "/etc/apache2/ports.conf"
    run "#{try_sudo} chmod -R 0777 #{ports_file}" 

    check = %x( cat '/etc/apache2/ports.conf' )
    puts check

    unless /Listen 8581/.match check
        run "#{try_sudo} sed -i '$ a\Listen 8581\n' #{ports_file}"
    end
    run "#{try_sudo} chmod -R 0644 #{ports_file}"
end
```

I ran this cap task and the variable 'check' always prints ports.conf which is in my local. What i want is the contents from server.

When i ran this cap task i was asked server password. I also tried cap deploy. Same result. What may be the pblm.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to execute a command remotely, you need to call `run` like you did in all other places!

Comment: Actually I need the output of run() in the variable check. Luckily there is a method capture() which satisfied my exact need. thanks any way. It appears like a simple question and yet nobody gave the right answer..pity

Answer (score 0):

```
check = capture("cat /etc/apache2/ports.conf")
```

Did the trick. This method capture() returns the result of the cmd passed.